# Blazor httpClient.PostJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

When I use HtttpClient in my Blazor server app application Asp.net core 3.1, when using the event for Log in with PostJsonAsyn I get an error in the browser console (I clarify that on my login page I do not see any error at the code level, only that happens to me when I try to do the login of a person in my blazor app)

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
> indicate success: 404 (Not Found). at
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions.SendJsonAsync[T](HttpClient
> httpClient, HttpMethod method, String requestUri, Object content) at
> arathsbaby_web.Pages.Users.Login.ValidateUser() in
> C:\Users\81416\Desktop\ArathsBaby-master\ArathsBaby\frontend\arathsbaby_web\Pages\Users\Login.razor:line
> 56 at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync() at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
> taskToHandle)

This would be my event, in which PostJsonAsync is used to send the response, but it doesn't work (try using PostAsJson but I was flaxing an error with my userInfo object as it cannot be converted to int)

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateUser()
{
    //string endpoint = $"{baseUrl}api/Users/Login";

    var rpta = await Http.PostJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);

    //SendJsonAsync<int>(HttpMethod.Post,endpoint,userInfo);

    //

    //PostAsJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);

    if (rpta !=0)
    {
        ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)auth).UserLogin(rpta.ToString());
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("catalog");
    }
    else
    {
        LoginMesssage = "Correo o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

This would be my handler for the user to log in (I'm not using any Identity or tokens as it would take me a little longer to finish the project)

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Accont/Login")]
    public int Login([FromBody] UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        int rpta = 0;
        int nvces;
        try
        {
            using (ArathsBabyContext db = new ArathsBabyContext())
            {
                nvces = db.Users.Where(p => p.Email == userInfo.Email
                 && p.Password == userInfo.Password).Count();
                if (nvces == 0)
                {
                    rpta = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    nvces = db.Users.Where(p => p.Email == userInfo.Email
                 && p.Password == userInfo.Password).First().Id;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rpta = 0;
        }

        return rpta;
    }
```

I also try using sendJsonAsync, thinking that this way the errro could be corrected but when I try to get to my app I appeared the following error in the browser console.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
> indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed). at
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions.SendJsonAsync[T](HttpClient
> httpClient, HttpMethod method, String requestUri, Object content) at
> arathsbaby_web.Pages.Users.Login.ValidateUser() in
> C:\Users\81416\Desktop\ArathsBaby-master\ArathsBaby\frontend\arathsbaby_web\Pages\Users\Login.razor:line
> 57 at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync() at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
> taskToHandle)

And that's how I've got the event with `SendJsonAsync`

```
`private async Task<bool> ValidateUser(){

string endpoint = $"{baseUrl}api/Users/Login";

var rpta = await Http.SendJsonAsync<int>(HttpMethod.Post,endpoint,userInfo);
    
//PostJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);

//PostAsJsonAsync<int>($"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login", userInfo);

if (rpta !=0)
{
    ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)auth).UserLogin(rpta.ToString());
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("catalog");
}
else
{
    LoginMesssage = "Correo o contraseña incorrectos";
}
return await Task.FromResult(true);
}´
```

What I wanted to know is why what PostJsonAsync is doesn't work for me in my blazor App, I don't know if I'm missing some kind of library or because it gives me that error.

Comment: When you debug `$"{baseUrl}api/Accont/Login"`, is there a `/` before `api/` ?

Comment: yes `private const string baseUrl = "https://localhost:44348/";´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your routing setup or controller name, I'm guessing the routing name is wrong.
If your controller name is `UsersController` then try this:
`[Route("Login")]` . The default routing for api controllers sets up the route `baseurl/api/[controllername]/`. (The routing cuts of the `Controller` from the route name.

Answer (score 0):

The error marked me because my app couldn't find my handler, in this case I had it as [HttpPost]*[Route("api/Accont/Login")]* by that Route the api couldn't find my contoler so it gave me that error, so I decided to remove it and just leave the route that I have as the controller header